# load iframe only after it triggered

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, iframe

i want to make popup with a 'iframe' in it, but when i open the website it also load the website in the iframe(and it take more time to load the web page).
this is the iframe code:

```
<div id="popup1" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">open</a>
    <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" width="100%" height="100%" data-overlay-theme="b">
          <p>This is my picture!</p> 
          <a href="#pageone" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
        <iframe width="100%" height="700em" name="iframe_pop" src="http://www.w3schools.com/">
          <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
        </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
```

how could i make the iframe website load only when i click the "open" link?

Comment: You mean using a button click event and then load the iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQM popup widget provides events including afterOpen: http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#event-afteropen

You can handle this event and load the iframe if it has not already been loaded:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" width="100%" height="100%" data-overlay-theme="b">
    <p>This is my picture!</p> <a href="#pageone" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    <iframe width="100%" height="300px" name="iframe_pop" id="iframe_pop" src="about:blank">
        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
</div>


$("#myPopup").on( "popupafteropen", function( event, ui ) {
    var $iframe = $("#iframe_pop");
    if ($iframe.prop("src") == 'about:blank'){
        $iframe.prop("src", "http://www.w3schools.com/");
    }        
});
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rpv77jzn/1/)**

Comment: why if i change the url to for example http://www.reddit.com/ or http://www.google.com/ it doesnt work? (and can you help me with another thing?: how can i change the height and width of the iframe, i tried with css but only the width changed and not the height)

Comment: @hhgjgj, set width using the .ui-popup-container, set height on the iframe either via CSS or on popupbeforeposition: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rpv77jzn/3/  Not all websites allow themselves to run within frames because of click-jacking issues. research frame busting.

Comment: if websites doesnt allow to put them inside iframe, does there is diffrent ways to put them inside a website?

Comment: @hhgjgj you can load them into a new window or new tab. You can use AJAX to get the HTML of the site and load that into a div, but you would lose some functionality of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want your iframe to load when a button is clicked.

First set your `iframe`'s source  to `abut:blank`

```
<iframe width="100%" height="700em" name="iframe_pop" src="about:blank">
```

At the end of your `body` tag add a `script` tag.
Since you provided the JQuery tags I think you are familiar with Javascript.

```
<body> 
    ...
    <script>
        $("#myPopup").click(function(){
            $("iframe").attr("src", "http://www.w3schools.com/");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```